# Upadate TreeView From Class .cs

Tags: c#, wpf

Good morning for all;

I have a TreeView in my Window WPF, I use DataBinding to cover my TreeView.

Now I have another Class MyDesign.cs , and I want to upade the itms of my TreeView from this Class.

here My code:

***MainWindow.xaml:***

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewAndDataBanding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:TreeViewAndDataBanding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyDesignContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Paste}"/>

            <MenuItem Header="Search" Command="{x:Static self:MyDesign.Search}"/>
        </ContextMenu>



        <self:test x:Key="test"/>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="23*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="MyToolBox"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource test}" Grid.Column="1" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="All Cars">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path= Voiture}">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Vitesse}"></TreeViewItem>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                        </TreeViewItem>

                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <s:MyDesign Focusable="true" x:Name="MyDesigner"

                            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                            Margin="10" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                            ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyDesignContextMenu}" Grid.Coulum="0"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***MenuItem.cs***

```
  namespace TreeViewAndDataBanding
    {
        public class MenuItem
        {
            private string _Voiture;
            private string _Vitesse;

            public MenuItem( string Voiture,string Vitesse)
            {
                this._Voiture = Voiture;
                this._Vitesse = Vitesse;
           }

            public string Voiture
            {
                get { return _Voiture; } 
            }

            public string Vitesse
            {
                get { return _Vitesse; }
            }
        }
    }
```

***test.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TreeViewAndDataBanding
{
    public class test : ObservableCollection<MenuItem> 
    {
       public test()
       {
           Add(new MenuItem("Rapide", "Ferrari F430"));

       }


    }
}
```

***And here My class MyDesign.Command.Cs, I want to be able to update my treeView in this Class (in method Search)***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TreeViewAndDataBanding
{
    public class MyDesign
    {
        public static RoutedCommand Search = new RoutedCommand();

        public MyDesign()
        {
            this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste, Paste_Executed));

            this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste, Search_Executed));
        }


        private void Search_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // d'ici je veux modifier mon TreeView

            /******************************************************************************************/
            /****** ici je veux modifier  et mettre a jour mon Treeview dans l'interface *************/
            /****************************************************************************************/


        }



        private void Paste_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }




    }
}
```

Can You help me please,?? any ideas??

Comment: Starting with reading up on MVVM and downloading some examples of TreeView + MVVM projects.

Comment: I can't do this without MVVM ??

Comment: If you want to do WPF right, you should learn about MVVM. It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this MVVM style is much cleaner, easier to maintain, and makes WPF make a lot more sense. An example (I've renamed a few things as my French is well. non-existent)

Create a ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<CarType> CarTypes { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel() {
        CarsTypes = new ObservableCollection<CarType>();
        var sportsCars = new CarType("Sports cars");
        sportscars.Cars.Add(new Car() { Make = "Ferrari", Model = "F430" });
        CarTypes.Add(sportsCars);
    }
}
```

And your View:

```
<Window ...
    <Window.DataContext>
         <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" DataType="{x:Type local:CarType}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Make}"/>
                <TextBlock> - </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CarTypes}"/>
</Window>
```

Please note that I typed above directly into SO, so I haven't compiled it. I may contains a few errors. But as you can see, using MVVM, this is very little code.

Now you can just add new instances to the Collection on the ViewModel, and your UI will update. Commands can be implemented on the ViewModel using `RelayCommands`.